# Is that possible of using println directly as a String output in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am very curious if I can use println directly in my interface , this will reduce my time of showing prototype to customer without write specific function to iterating through a complex data.
In another word ,what I want achieve is something like :

```
textView.text = println(object)
```

I am appreciate for any fantastic approaches !
Regards.

Comment: Have you tried/read this http://vperi.com/2014/06/04/textual-representation-for-classes-in-swift/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toString()` function returns the same thing that a `println()` would print to the console:

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let xsString = toString(xs)
// xsString == "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

In your case, `textView.text = toString(object)` would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .description

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let myArrayDescription = myArray.description // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
let myDateDescription = NSDate().description // "2015-01-13 18:57:15 +0000"
// you can also use it with current locale
let myDateDescriptionWithLocale = NSDate().descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())! // "Tuesday, January 13, 2015 at 4:59:07 PM Brasilia Summer Time"
```

Comment: is .description is available for AnyObject?

Comment: No, only for Printable's.  Which actually includes `AnyObject` but not `Any`, so yes...

Comment: Thanks , I preferred use this